# LINQ sorting on sub table converted to CSV

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have an EF model (note joined partial classes togther for clarity)

```
public class Product
{
    public System.Guid ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Product{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ModulesCSV
    {
        get
        {
            string retList = "";
            foreach (Module aModule in Modules)
            {
                if (retList.Length > 0)
                    retList += ", ";
                retList += aModule.Module.Trim ();
            }
            return retList;
        }
    }
 }
```

now I need to sort on the CSV as well as the other columns, I realise that link to sql has problems wth this.  My normal sort cannot do this I was wondering if anyone knows a good way of doing it va LINQ and could please share it?

The current sort line is where 'sort' is the column name and 'sortdir' is "ASC" or "DESC" which works a treat for the other columns.
    query = db.Products.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).OrderBy(sort + " " + sortdir);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pretty or as efficient but
 if (sort != "CSV")   // as non ddb column has to be sorted on list
                query = db.Products.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).OrderBy(sort + " " + sortdir);
            else
            {
                query = db.Products.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);

```
            if (sortdir=="ASC")
            {
                query = db.Products.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList<Product>().AsQueryable <Product> ();
                query = query.OrderBy(r => r.GetType().GetProperty(sort).GetValue(r, null));
            }
            else
            {
                query = db.Products.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList<Product>().AsQueryable <Product> ();
                query = query.OrderByDescending(r => r.GetType().GetProperty(sort).GetValue(r, null));
            }
        }
```